# Change linewidth in python plotly px figure

Tags: python, plotly

I'm unclear how to style a line in a plotly express figure, altering color and width. The [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/) offers suggestions to style lines using go, but I do not see information for px.

Example

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')
fig.show()
```

I tried putting `line=dict(color='firebrick', width=4)` as an argument of `px.line` but that throws the error `line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'line'` as it is code for go rather than px.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Plotly px line styles can be updated with `update_traces` function see [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#updating-traces) for further information. The following example modifies the prior figure making all of the lines black and thin.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')

# This styles the line
fig.update_traces(line=dict(color="Black", width=0.5))

fig.show()
```